# Using the time as css background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datetime, background-color

Just for fun, I wanted to make my website have a dynamic background color that's an rgb value based on the current time. I did some googling and came up with the following, but it's not working.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link type="text/javascript" src="date.js">
    <style>
        p{
        font-size: 150%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

date.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function(){currentTime("#idTimeField")}, 500);
});
function currentTime(field) {
var now = new Date();
now = (now.getHours() * 10) + ', ' + (now.getMinutes() * 4) + ', ' + (now.getSeconds() * 4);
$(field).val(now);
}

document.getElementsByName("html").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + now + ")";
```

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong, or an alternate/better way to do this?
I apologize if I did something stupid, I'm quite a javascript noob

Thanks in advance

Comment: now is declared inside `currentTIme` function - so you can't access it outside of the function ... why not put that last line that sets the background colour inside the currentTime function

Comment: also, you may need to document.getElementsBy**Tag**Name

Comment: I'm just wondering why you make the function in jQuery, and then use regular js for the assignment. You've already loaded jQuery, why not just use jQuery for all of it?

Comment: @TheLazySloth - bringing it our of `currentTIme` wont continuously change the bg colour :p

Comment: or why use jQuery for any of it :p

Comment: actually getElementsByTagName wont help ... use document.body.parentElement instead

Comment: @TheLazySloth - wont matter where it's instantiated ... the bg colour would change exactly once and nver again if that code is not inside the interval code

Comment: You might also want a pure CSS infinite animation. Just type it in your prefered search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line is out of function. And `document.getElementByName` doesn't work for `html` tag you should use `document.getElementByTagName`.

Overal use this instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function(){currentTime("#idTimeField")}, 500);
});


function currentTime(field) {
  var now = new Date();
  now = (now.getHours() * 10) + ', ' + (now.getMinutes() * 4) + ', ' + (now.getSeconds() * 4);
  $(field).val(now);
  $('body').css('background-color', "rgb(" + now + ")");

}
```

Comment: body !== html element

Comment: @JaromandaX Nope, take a look at here: https://css-tricks.com/html-vs-body-in-css/

Comment: are those "quirks" guaranteed to remain in effect? Why not code properly and avoid dependencies on quirks (unless of course, the quirky behaviour is actually following some specification - which isn't clear from that site) - PS, thanks for the lesson :p I never knew about that

Answer (score 0):

Here. All jQuery. Code modified to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function(){currentTime("#idTimeField")}, 500);
});
function currentTime(field) {
  var now = new Date();
  now = (now.getHours() * 10) + ', ' + (now.getMinutes() * 4) + ', ' + (now.getSeconds() * 4);
  $(field).val(now);
  $('html,body').css({'background-color':'rgb('+now+')'});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link type="text/javascript" src="date.js">
    <style>
        p{
        font-size: 150%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="idTimeField">20:10:34</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function(){currentTime("#idTimeField")}, 500);
});
function currentTime() {
var now = new Date();
var R = (now.getHours() * 10) ;
var G = (now.getMinutes() * 4) ;
var B = (now.getSeconds() * 4);
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + [R,G,B].join(',') + ')';
}
```